# What will be scenarios if I implement the network check like following in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, networking, kotlin

Am trying to check my Internet availability before making API calls. But found out some of the methods are **deprecated** so found one solution on my own and it's working fine. But need to know about it's long term use.

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
        var isNetwork: Boolean = false
        val connectivityManager = context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetwork

        if (activeNetwork == null) {
            isNetwork = false
            Toast.makeText(context, "What can we do to that ?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //Here we can show no network screen
        } else {
            isNetwork = true
        }

        return isNetwork
    }
```

The `activeNetwork` becomes null if the device is **not** connected to internet. Is it a right way to implement? Your expertise needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    fun isInternetConnected(context: Context): Boolean {
        return try {
            val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
                val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                capabilities != null &&
                        (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR))
            } else {
                (context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager).activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected == true
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here also shows one deprecated method. `Getter for activeNetworkInfo: NetworkInfo! is deprecated. Deprecated in java.
`
Am worried about those methods

Comment: This deprecated method is only for the devices running Android version lower than Marshmello thats why I put this in if-else condition.

Comment: So is it okay to use this way? Any views on my implementation that why it's not a ideal way?